# Android Searchview on top

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, searchview

I want put ont top layout SearchView. I have MyActivity with SearcView and below it there is RecyclerView, when i open MyActivity it show first RecyclerView, if i want see SearchView i scroll upward. How i set MyActivity so that when i open MyActivity, it show me first SearchView?

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillViewport="true">

 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <SearchView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:queryHint="Evento"
            android:id="@+id/cercaEvento"/>

    </LinearLayout>
 ......
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Place the SearchView on the Action Bar or Toolbar. Then it will remain on top always.

Comment: Is there solution for my problem?

Comment: Yeah. SearchView should be placed in a Menu Item. A working code can be given.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.this is solve your problem

http://javapapers.com/android/android-searchview-action-bar-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout>
   <SearchView>
   <RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```